# How to use aws cli command to check s3 file information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have checked the `aws s3` command helper. I didn't find how to see the file information in S3.

For example, I have a video file in S3, I want to see the media information, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple...**No you cannot**.

Amazon S3 is a simple key, value store which stores data as objects. It stores the data regardless of what format it is and doesn't differentiate between any file format. Hence, you cannot retrieve any information regarding the files(whether it be jpeg,zip,pdf,text **anything**)

Comment: This is not strictly true. You can get the content type and any other metadata that you added to the object. The catch there is that you have to put that metadata yourself if you don't want to have to download the whole object to get it.